# Style specific dates in jquery ui datepicker plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm writing an app for reserving training facilities, and I want to be able to let the instructor reserving a facility know when the facility is already reserved for a given date.

I'm using the jquery-UI datepicker plugin, and I want to be able to style the table cells for these reserved dates differently. I just can't figure out how to pass the dates into the plugin so I can change the class for those dates on the calendar.

Answer (score 6):

I would make use of the beforeShowDay event to deal with this.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Comment: The answer is correct, but the link in the answer doesn't seem to show a demo of it anymore - however...
This is a worked example: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html

And this is the documentation for the event:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay